# Do preemptible instances live longer on old zones?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've had instances be killed within a few minutes in peak hour. Would less busy zones with old processor architectures live longer on average?

The reasoning goes that they should be less busy and preemptible instances are designed to optimize dormant resources... of which old zones should have more of.

Update:
While this question has an answer, it appears it would probably take a small collaboration ( or a medium to large business IT ) to answer this question... as such this may be better suited to a discussion board.

Answer (score 1):

No one but Google has the data to answer this question. I would be very careful about making any assumptions on this issue.

Comment: it would literally take about a day to get some very rough data on this. With preemptible instances, you don't need to be careful, that's the point. They will be killed at random points and live at most 24 hours. Also, any company that's extensively using preemptible instances would have have tons of data in their logs on this.